# mixing JQuery and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to use the JQuery effects in the existing Xcode project?

Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're talking about. You're probably going to need to add some detail that describes your project.

Comment: I think you're a little confused. jQuery is JavaScript, which runs primarily in a web browser (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera, etc.). Objective-C runs primarily on OS X computers and iOS devices made by Apple.

Comment: i have some set of UIViews and i want to add the JQuery effects to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer without more details is probably no, inasmuch as Objective-c is a compiled language that produces a runtime package that will run on the appropriate devices and JQuery is a set of javascript libraries that are interpreted when run in a browser or or on a server side javascript engine such as NodeJs.

It's possible you might be writing an application in Xcode that users a browser window so once you are inside a browser then the answer might be yes you can run JQuery inside that but this supposes that you are writing html/js inside this area.

THe other question would be why do you want to? If you are writing XCode then you have full access to all the Apple UI's which are native to the touch devices you are developing for and probably (certainly) give you a much wider set of options.

Comment: I want to use the Jquery for the effects and animations in my existing project..
I am new to objective C.. :(

Suppose I have a UIView and i want the panning effect in it. Is is possible to use both of them together coz i want to use it jus for the animation and effects.

Comment: i think you need to reread the answers and the comments about being unable to run JQuery, a web based set of libraries in a non web based application. If you want to achieve an effect that you have seen in jquery in x-code then you will need to read the Apple UI (user interface) guides to match up with an existing effect and in the UI libraries and then implement that or simply write your own objective-c libraries, thier are xcode projects to do this with and implement it. If you really want jquery on the iPhone then use Sencha touch to building web based iPhone apps that use jquery

Comment: okiess... 

i got it now... :)
i'll create effects in obj C.. 
Thanks alot... :)

Comment: Cool, best of luck. I ran out of room a bit in the last comment but there was a project called JQTouch which emulated the UI of the iPhone in JavaScript and sat on top of JQuery giving you JQ effects on the phone. This is now part of a company called Sencha. BUT it is a web based solution not one that is native to the iPhone so it is different from XCode. YOu also need to remember that JQuery effects are designed for Mouse, Keyboard and a large hi resolution screen whereas iPhone UI is designed fro smaller lower resolution screens with a finger/touch interface.

Comment: @iShrey you can't do that. JS has no way to interact with ObjC such directly.